# Atributo v-on:change no funciona cuando cambio el valor con un botón en VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal y si alguien me puede corregir, yo necesito que al modificarse el `input` se ejecute un `metodo`, si yo cambio el valor directamente en el `input` funciona sin problemas, pero si doy clic en el botón que es el que me cambia el valor de la variable, no se efectúa la acción

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      return{
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        count : 0
      }
  },
  methods: {
    contar: function (event) {
      this.count +=1;
    },
    contar2: function (event) {
      this.count *=5;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <input v-model="count" v-on:change="contar2">
  <button v-on:click="contar">suma</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Aclaro que no necesito ejecutar las dos funciones a la vez, el ejemplo lo puse así porque era la forma mas sencilla de expresar mi caso, espero me puedan ayudar a entender, porque según yo en teoría debería funcionar.

Comment: @Marcos Es sencillo lo que pregunto, el `v-on:change` no funciona cuando cambio el valor del `input ` con el botón.

Comment: @Marcos estaba revisando lo de las `directives` de la siguiente forma `directives: {
                update: function (el, binding) {
                    alert(this.count);
                }
        }` pero no me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Después de buscar y buscar encontré la respuesta a lo que necesitaba, el atributo `v-on:change` no funcionaba porque efectivamente como mencionaba Marcos, el cambio se estaba generando en la programación y no desde el `input`.

En los casos en los que se genera un cambio a una variable desde la programación, se debe utilizar el `watch` como muestro a continuación:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      return{
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        count : 0,
        count2 : 0
      }
  },
  methods: {
    contar: function (event) {
      this.count +=1;
    },
    contar2: function (event) {
      this.count2 =this.count * 5;
    }
  },
  watch: {

     count : function () {
       this.contar2()
     }

  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <input v-model="count" style="display:none">
  <button v-on:click="contar">suma</button>
  <br>
  <input v-model="count2" >
  
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Me vi en la necesidad de modificar ligeramente el código `html` porque al hacer que funcionará caí en un bucle infinito ya que al siempre detectar la modificación, siempre se iba a ejecutar el `methods` `contar2` Para mayor información, se puede revisar la [documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que estás modificando el valor del `input` *prográmaticamente*, el cual no dispara un evento.

### Solución:

Si buscas una "*reacción en cadena*", lo más simple es llamar a `contar2()` desde `contar()`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
      return{
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        count : 0
      }
  },
  methods: {
    contar: function (event) {
      this.count +=1;
      this.contar2(); // Ejecutamos manualmente el método
    },
    contar2: function (event) {
      this.count *=5;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <input v-model="count" @input="contar2">
  <button @click="contar">suma</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: Ya encontré la forma de hacerlo Marco, voy a publicar la respuesta por si alguien mas esta en mi situación.